# Grails criteria sum 2 property

Tags: grails, sum, criteria

I have a criteria function, I'd like to sum installPay and bonusPay but it just sum only installPay. My tried is below.

```
def c = ServiceOrder.createCriteria()
        def aaa = c.list {
            or {
                eq('baseBatch', payment)
                eq('bonusBatch', payment)
            }
            isNull('service')
            projections {
                groupProperty('installer')
                sum('installPay', 'bonusPay')
            }
            order("installer", "asc")
        }
```

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        projections {
            groupProperty('installer')
            sum 'installPay'
            sum 'bonusPay'
        }
```